# Requesting a server for images and server responding with images

Tags: django, image, httprequest

Hi I am writing a webapp for learning purposes.

Currently I am stuck at the part where, everything else loads but not the image files.

I am using django 1.4.5 with python 2.7.4.

This is the urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^frontend/finalImages/(.*)/$', loadImages),
)
```

This is the views.py file:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def loadImages(request, text):
    print text
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype="image/png")
    img = Image.open("mysite/frontend/finalImages/"+text)
    img.save(response,'png')
    return response
```

I am requesting for the image files in the JS code as follows:

```
img = new Image();
img.src='/frontend/final images/1010.png";
```

I am not getting any error in running the code but, the images are not loading up.

Console:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/frontend/finalImages/1010.png 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

what am i doing wrong. How to achieve this!

Comment: NOTE: @tMJ understand two things 1. Django doesn't serve static in production so you need some sort of Nginx process taking care of serving static. 2. You need to specify STATICFILES_DIR as mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

Comment: I dont understand the "static" serving thing. I have been up all night trying to implement that, but it hasn't worked out for me. I have visited before, the question you linked, I didn;t understand a thing. 
And I need to respond with images only in debugging mode, not production. SO no worries there. 

NOTE: I am rookie.

Comment: can you share you settings.py file in gist or something. Also let me know if you're using local_setting.py ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5558916

Note: I had to accomodate the css and js onto the html file itself, because I couldn't figure out a way to load them separatel. No local_settings.

Comment: Assuming your static is located in one level up relative to your setting.py file. Look at my comment in gist. Configure that. It should allow you to server static if you're doing simple python manage.py runserver

Comment: Yeah 404 is gone. 
Now some internal server error. 

aarrghh .
thanks a lot saviour!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your folder called static is at parent level of you settings.py following changes in settings.py file should help

`STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..','static'),
)`